# IIS 7 Directory Browsing for specific IP range

Tags: iis-7

is it possible to allow directory browsing in IIS7 only for a specific IP range? (e.g. for internal users 10.1.10/24)

As far I only see options to enable or disable it entirely.

Regards,
Fionn

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. First you need to install the

Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on and off > Roles > Add Roles Services:

Under Security select 'IP and Domain Restrictions' and install.

Alternatively you can install it using this command line command:

`ServerManagerCmd -install Web-IP-Security`

You will then see an additional icon in IIS manager with which you can add IP/domain restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you could create a second web site that points to the same content, enable directory browsing, and restrict access to the web site to the ip range in question. You would then use a different URL for the two web sites.

Comment: Since i need the same URL this wouldn't be very useful.